# Возможно ли такой задний фон сделать только CSS стилями?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этой картинке будет какой-то контент и при адаптиве он по высоте расширяется.

И вопрос в следующем, как можно данную форму заднего фона сделать только на css?

Comment: clip-path: polygon(100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0 0, 50% 20%, 100% 0); background: white;

Comment: отдельные вопросы надо задавать (как бы это странно ни звучало) отдельными вопросами.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Не согласен, если нужно реализовать только CSS способом. То кому-то да поможет.

Comment: @Andew согласен, вопрос должен звучать по другому, так как пока внутрь задачи не зайдёшь, не поймёшь, что требуется, а в поиске люди не будут искать по названию - "Возможно ли такой задний фон сделать только CSS стилями?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это именно задний фон, то вариантов дохрена.

1. `clip-path`, как вам показали в комментариях, у элемента, спозиционированного позади. Или у псевдоэлемента.
2. `transform:skew(0deg, 5deg)` у псеводэлемента :before и `transform:skew(0deg, -5deg)` - у :after. Ну и плюс прочие свойства.
3. фон из двух косых градиентов:

```css
{
background-image: linear-gradient(4deg, transparent, 
transparent 20px, gray 20px, gray calc(100% - 20px), 
transparent calc(100% - 20px)), linear-gradient(-4deg, 
transparent, transparent 20px, gray 20px, gray calc(100% - 
20px), transparent calc(100% - 20px));

background-size: 50% 100%, 50% 100%;

background-position: top left, top right;

background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
```

Можно еще повыделываться...

Answer (score 0):

примерный эскиз блоков можно вот так дальше на усмторение

```css
.block1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.block2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: -95px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Comment: ну и добавить в целм все это в backgorund("")

Comment: вы всё правильно мыслите, но не правильно реализовали. Нужно было оставить только один блок и ему задать position: relative; overflow: hidden;, потом создать ему псевдоклассы и им уже задавать такие фигуры.

Comment: По задаче тут больше `skewY` подойдёт, чем `rotate()`.